# Running kubectl commands Helm post install

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to run some `kubectl` commands to verify the cluster post install of Helm charts. I could not find any documentation around this. In Helm, theres the concept of showing notes as part of `NOTES.txt` but doesnt look like you can run any commands at that stage.

Is this currently impossible to do with Helm ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `job` that is executed at a certain point in the [lifecycle](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#hooks-and-the-release-lifecycle) during `helm install`. The [list of available hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#the-available-hooks) also contains a `post-install` hook you are probably looking for. An [example](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook) can be found in the official documentation.

You basically provide a Kubernetes Job, add necessary helm labels and then also an annotation like this:

```yaml
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install
```

In case you are looking for something running on the client side, maybe you can [use or create a Helm plugin](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/plugins/). There is a list in the official documentation: [Helm Plugins](https://helm.sh/docs/community/related/#helm-plugins). You can find some more by filtering GitHub repositories for the topic [helm-plugin](https://github.com/topics/helm-plugin).

There are ideas for [future development](https://github.com/helm/community/blob/master/hips/archives/helm/helm-v3/005-plugins.md) to support `Lua` for scripting plugins. But the current format will still be supported.

Comment: Thanks @webwurst I'm aware of the hooks but was wondering if there was any other way to output some sort of report at the end by running a command. Doesnt running a script as a job swallow the output ?

Comment: Ok, so you are looking for something running on the client side? Maybe you can [use or create](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) a [Helm plugin](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/related.md#helm-plugins) for that. To get the output of `job` running within the Kubernetes cluster you would need to run something like `kubectl logs`.

Comment: Yeah on the client side. Sorry I should have been more specific. I think a plugin might be the way to go then. Thanks once again.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer and il mark it as answered.