# Helm Hook to run kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I would like to run `kubectl` command from a pre-upgrade `helm hook`, but I can't seem to any documentation on how to achieve this.

Do I have to create a docker image that contains `kubectl` in order to achieve this?

or is there some way of achieving this without using a container?

I have a basic `helm hook` which looks like this

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-change-pvc-hook
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded, before-hook-creation
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: "{{.Release.Name}}"
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
        - name: pre-upgrade-change-pvc
```

if someone could explain how to run `kubectl` on without a container or how I can achieve this, that would be great

Comment: What actions do you intend to execute using `kubectl` during an upgrade?

Comment: Hi @EduardoBaitello, I am looking to run a `kubectl patch pvc` to change the access type.

Comment: @user3292394 are you try to achieve this on your local env (minikube, kubeadm) or any cloud providers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to create a docker image that contains kubectl in order to
>   achieve this?

Yes, you have to create it because containers usually are Lightweight and contain the most basic stuff. 
You can create container with kubernetes using [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Second option is to create own [mutating webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) which will modify PVC (using [patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/)).

> Mutating admission Webhooks are invoked first, and can modify objects
>   sent to the API server to enforce  custom defaults. After all object
>   modifications are complete, and after the incoming object is validated
>   by the API server, validating admission webhooks are invoked and can
>   reject requests to enforce custom policies.

This way you could modify PVC before `Helm install` will create release.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like Prometheus operator does the cleanup (pre-delete hook) in their helm chart: [prometheus operator kubectl usage](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/d58247103fafd5930792bb1fd3ac240547523200/stable/prometheus-operator/templates/prometheus-operator/cleanup-crds.yaml#L33)

basically, you can use the image = `k8s.gcr.io/hyperkube:v1.12.1`
something like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name:somename-operator-cleanup
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "3"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
  labels:
    app: someapp-operator
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: somename-operator-cleanup
      labels:
        app: someapp
    spec:
    {{- if .Values.global.rbac.create }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "prometheus-operator.operator.serviceAccountName" . }}
    {{- end }}
      containers:
        - name: kubectl
          image: "k8s.gcr.io/hyperkube:v1.12.1"
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          command:
          - /bin/sh
          - -c
          - >
              kubectl your command here.
              kubectl delete alertmanager   --all;
              kubectl delete prometheus     --all;
              kubectl delete prometheusrule --all;
              kubectl delete servicemonitor --all;
              sleep 10;
              kubectl delete crd alertmanagers.monitoring.coreos.com;
              kubectl delete crd prometheuses.monitoring.coreos.com;
              kubectl delete crd prometheusrules.monitoring.coreos.com;
              kubectl delete crd servicemonitors.monitoring.coreos.com;
              kubectl delete crd podmonitors.monitoring.coreos.com;
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Other option is to CURL to the Kubernetes API like [here](https://github.com/ethz-hpc/k8s-OpenNebula/blob/2bbec2e31ca20159a51abbf7d51624d8e86ac1f2/Chart/templates/auto-ssh-secret-job.yaml#L42)
note you need `automountServiceAccountToken: true`
and then you can use the Barear token from `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`

You just need an image with curl for that. You can use zakkg3/opennebula-alpine-bootstrap for this.

For example here i create a secret based on a file using curl instead of kubectl:

```
url -s -X POST -k https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/${NAMESPACE}/secrets \
                -H "Authorization: Bearer $( cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token )" \
                -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                -H "Accept: application/json" \
                -d "{ \"kind\": \"Secret\", \"apiVersion\": \"v1\", \"metadata\": { \"name\": \"{{ include "opennebula.fullname" . }}-ssh-keys\", \"namespace\": \"${NAMESPACE}\" }, \"type\": \"Opaque\", \"data\": { \"authorized_keys\": \"$( cat opennebula-ssh-keys/authorized_keys | base64 | tr -d '\n' )\", \"config\": \"$( cat opennebula-ssh-keys/config | base64 | tr -d '\n' )\", \"id_rsa\": \"$( cat opennebula-ssh-keys/id_rsa | base64 | tr -d '\n' )\", \"id_rsa.pub\": \"$( cat opennebula-ssh-keys/id_rsa.pub | base64 | tr -d '\n' )\" } }" > /dev/null
```

Note its good practice to output to >  /dev/null otherwise you will end up with this output in your logging management (ELK / LOKI).

Answer (score 0):

I am looking to do something like this with my helm hooks.

In my looking around I have found this question: 
[Running kubectl commands Helm post install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077574/running-kubectl-commands-helm-post-install)

But it doesn't offer much, I am currently looking into the helm plugins
https://helm.sh/docs/related/#helm-plugins

Hope you find your answer

Comment: Thanks, @niall-maher , I will take a look into helm hooks